# kendo angular 2 grid cusomized data binding issue when service call picks new data will not binding

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/#toc-auto-generated-columns

```
Here Dynamically columns binding is missing:

The First time data binding correctly. The second time onwards it's not binding why?

this.gridData ---> is the Api response data

 this.gridView = {enter code here
          data: this.gridData,
          total: this.petService.pets.length
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "the second tume onwards"? How exactly is the Grid supposed to be updated?

If the object the Grid is bound to is updated each time new data arrives, the Grid will be rerendered accordingly with the latest data, e.g.:

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*sampleCustomers.length);
        this.gridData = sampleCustomers.slice(rnd, rnd + 10)
      }, 1000);
    }
```

[EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/vQxbpgcnzLv1LlxBfAI7?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Sir..! This is not working for me. May be My explanation is wrong. what i need while pulling request the data will be bind with dynamic header and data. where as coming to second request on wards the first request data unmatched columns data will be bind other than this not working.

Comment: Please help me if possible. I work on angular material it's working and dynamically with html tables it's working  coming to kenod angular 2 ui grid.

Comment: I think I understand the issue. Once the column structure is dynamically inferred from the data, it cannot be further modified. I can suggest providing the columns via *ngFor and creating the new columns structure dynamically based on the incoming data, e.g.: